# Import Last Row Starting in Particular Column to Centralized Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, import

Looking for some help to only import rows that have been "filled in" from various worksheets to a centralized "Import" worksheet in the same workbook. Each tab in the workbook is a template, and not all rows have been filled in, but remain as a part of the template. See below for example:

```
Organic Fruit   Color   Quantity
Yes     Grapes  Purple  10
Yes     Banana  Yellow  15
Yes     Apple   Red     4
Yes     Orange
No      Kiwi
```

Let's say in the above example that the "Organic" and "Fruit" columns came pre-determined, but the "Color" and "Quantity" rows were filled in by various stakeholders - some rows were not filled out in this data collection cycle, but will be in the future. In this case, I would only be interested in importing the top 3 rows, because the "Orange" and "Kiwi" rows are not currently filled out. The number of rows I am interested in compiling in the centralized "Import" tab varies based on the each tab in the workbook (i.e. it is not a standard "top 3 rows").

Where in my below code can I modify in order to only import the rows that have been "filled out"? There are headers in the "Import" tab. If you have any suggestions to improve the overall code too, that is much appreciated

```
Sub CombineDataSheets()

    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range
    Dim rngDst As Range
    Dim lngSrcLastRow As Long    'Src is source
    Dim lngDstLastRow As Long    'Dst is destination

    'Set references

    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
    lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)

    'Set the initial destination range
    Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)    'edit the cells +/- forimportation into central tab in database


    'Loop through all sheets
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
        If wksSrc.Name <> "Import" And wksSrc.Name <> "Cover page" And wksSrc.Name <> "Introduction" Then

            'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
            lngSrcLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksSrc)

            'Store the source data (start of copy area is calibrated to table insheet) then copy it to the destination range
            With wksSrc
                Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(11, 2), .Cells(lngSrcLastRow, 21))
                rngSrc.Copy Destination:=rngDst
            End With

            'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
            lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(wksDst)
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lngDstLastRow + 1, 1)

        End If

    Next wksSrc

End Sub

Public Function LastOccupiedRowNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long
Dim lng As Long

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet.Cells) <> 0 Then
    With Sheet

       lng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("S1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
Else
    lng = 1
End If
LastOccupiedRowNum = lng
End Function
```

Comment: If the data was sorted with either Color or Quantity as the primary key then blanks should be at the bottom. Assign lngSrcLastRow to the last occupied Color or Quantity row.

Comment: is the data always displayed like the example, where columns 1 & 2 are typically filled in, then columns 3 and 4 are questionable?  if so, you can sort data by the row LEAST LIKELY to be filled out, then cells(rows.count,LeastLikelyColumn).end(xlup).row, and copy the range as such to the master sheet.

Comment: @Jeeped jinx you owe me a beer... apparently we submitted that at the same second.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the last row function -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your function using Columns("S"), I will make the same suggestion from Jeeped's and my comment: sort first, then copy the range.

Using an arbitrary range A < S < x to sort then copy:

```
dim lrs as Long, lrd as Long
For i = 1 to Sheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Name <> "Import" And Sheets(i).Name <> "Cover page" And Sheets(i).Name <> "Introduction" Then
        With Sheets(i)
            lrs = .cells(.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row    
            Sheets(i).Range("A1:AA" & lrs ).Sort key1:=Range("S1:S" & lrs), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            lrs = .cells(.rows.count,"S").end(xlup).row    
            .Range(.cells(2,"A"),.cells(lrs,"AA")).Copy
        End With
        With Sheets("Import")
            lrd = .cells(.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row
            .Range(.cells(lrd+1,"A"),.cells(lrd+1+lrs,"AA")).PasteSpecial xlValues
        End With
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Note: lrs = last row source, lrd = last row destination